# Why do all the android animator methods work only the first time? Then only the last method works

Tags: android, kotlin, animator

Why does my button only rotate on the first click after the activity is created? On the second and subsequent pressing of the button, the button only rises up and down along the Y axis.

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.clearChkBtn).setOnClickListener {
        val x = it.x
        val y = it.y
        it.animate().setDuration(3000).alpha(0.1f).rotation(540f).x(50f).y(50f).setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener{
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                       it.animate().setDuration(3000).alpha(1f).rotation(0f).x(x).y(y)
                }
                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) = Unit
                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) = Unit
                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) = Unit
        })
}
```

What it looks like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ovJAdZwNpw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and same happened for me, however the issue is that you need to clear the animation in order to perform it again, using

```
it.clearAnimation
```

but since you are applying again an animation to get it back, you need to add listener to new animation and clear it there this way

```
 it.animate().setDuration(3000).alpha(0.1f).rotation(359f).x(50f).y(50f).setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener{
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                it.animate().setDuration(3000).alpha(1f).rotation(0f).x(x).y(y).setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener{
                    override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {

                    }

                    override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
                        it.clearAnimation()
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {
                    }

                })

            }
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) = Unit
            override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) = Unit
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) = Unit
        })
    }
```

Comment: Another way to fix the situation is just to reset the listener. `it.animate().setDuration(3000).alpha(1f).rotation(0f).x(x).y(y).setListener(null)`. This fixes the issue too.

Comment: Looks good solution too.